# Homepage redirection for subdomain in Wordpress multisite

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, wildcard-subdomain, multisite

I am using wordpress multisite to manage my main site, which is membership-based, and one wildcard subdomain, which is a duplicate of the main site but for a different membership group.

On the main site, I am using the code at the bottom of my post to redirect all users from the homepage to an internal page, once they are logged into the site. However, on my subdomain, a logged in user is redirected to the same URL, when I need them to be redirected to "subdomain.redirecturlhere.com".

How can I supplement this code to give the subdomain version of my site its own redirection rule?

```
function logged_in_home_redirect() {

if( is_user_logged_in() && is_front_page() ) {

wp_redirect( '<REDIRECT URL HERE>' );

exit();

}

}

add_action( 'template_redirect', 'logged_in_home_redirect' );
```

Comment: Did you have multiple htaccess files?

Comment: No, I have one htaccess file. I actually am using the above code in a plugin, not htaccess.

Comment: I'm currently not close to my pc, therefore I cannot give you the htaccess code, but I that will be the best option for you.

Comment: Would the idea be that one htaccess file controls my main site and a second one controls my subdomain?

Comment: No only one htaccess file can be managed... However you can redirect urls

Comment: OK, that's what I thought but wasn't sure what you were suggesting. The part I can't figure out is how to differentiate between the main site's front page and the front page of my subdomain. The plugin using the code I've included works great -- I just need to modify it to target the subdomain.